# Different variables values for every host in group in ansible

Tags: configuration, ansible

I have a role in ansible that expects different variables. I want to apply this role to a host group but every host in the group needs different values for this role.

I tried to archive this with this configuration: 
Group Var:

```
host1: 
   var1: 'project a'
   var2: 'some other'

host2: 
   var1: 'project b'
   var2: 'some different'
```

hosts:

```
[myHosts]
host1
host2
```

But I have no clue how can I loop to the different hosts in a play

```
#something before

- hosts: myHosts
  become: true
  roles:
  - docker
  - docker-compose
  - git
  vars:
  - var1: ??
  # Something like this possible? 
  - var2: currentHost.var2
```

Or is my attempt wrong and I use the tool incorrect? 
This role is the last step for a deployment. So in the vars I want to say something like become project a or become project b. Would this be bad practice? Should I better have a role project a, project b and assign them to the specific host via playbook  even if the only difference between the two roles are some env variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the data in *`group_vars`* put the variables into a dictionary. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/myhosts.yml
my_dict:
  host1: 
    var1: 'project a'
    var2: 'some other'
  host2: 
    var1: 'project b'
    var2: 'some different'
```

Then, the variables may be easily "assigned" to each host

```yaml
- hosts: myhosts
  vars:
    var1: "{{ my_dict[inventory_hostname]['var1'] }}"
    var2: "{{ my_dict[inventory_hostname]['var2'] }}"
```

However, the best practice is to put such variables into the *`host_vars`* and let Ansible "assign" the variables to the hosts automatically. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host1.yml
var1: 'project a'
var2: 'some other'
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host2.yml
var1: 'project b'
var2: 'some different'
```

See [Group And Host Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#group-and-host-variables).

---

Notes

- To simplify the code and improve the readability, you can put the declarations of *`var*`* also into the *`group_vars`*. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/myhosts.yml
my_dict:
  host1: 
    var1: 'project a'
    var2: 'some other'
  host2: 
    var1: 'project b'
    var2: 'some different'

var1: "{{ my_dict[inventory_hostname]['var1'] }}"
var2: "{{ my_dict[inventory_hostname]['var2'] }}"
```

Comment: Thanks! I've searched for this to combine `--extra-vars` and inventory vars to keep the sensitive data in a gitignored file.
But with your recent edit I feel like it's worth to try more and stick to a more documented and simpler `host_vars`

Comment: To simplify the code and improve the readability, put the declarations of var* also into the group_vars. I added an example. You're welcome!